Stumped by Upgrade Message
Trying to upgrade to bullseye on Rasp Pi and I got a message I’ve never seen. How do I resolve this? I don’t need C or GCC for my personal needs.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done Calculating upgrade... Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet bee n created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situati on :
The following packages have unmet dependencies: libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-8-dev (< 8.4.0-2~) but 8.3.0-
6+rpil is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver:: Resolve generated breaks, t his may be caused by held packages.
Have no idea how to fix this…
